# Concatenate strings and integers

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

The following code gets me the result I want in the NSLog but there *must* be an easier way to do this? I'm also getting a 'format string is not a string literal' error, which still builds okay.

```
NSString *levelstring1 = @"Level ";
NSString *levelstring2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", levelscore];
NSString *levelstring3 = @" (";
NSString *levelstring4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", xpscore];
NSString *levelstring5 = @"/";
NSString *levelstring6 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (levelscore*(levelscore+1)*100)];
NSString *levelstring7 = @")";

NSString *levelstringfinal = [[[[[[levelstring1 stringByAppendingFormat:levelstring2]stringByAppendingFormat:levelstring3]stringByAppendingFormat:levelstring4]stringByAppendingFormat:levelstring5]stringByAppendingFormat:levelstring6]stringByAppendingFormat:levelstring7];

NSLog(@"Level is %@",levelstringfinal);
```

The end result looks something like this: Level 1 (50/100).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine them into something like:

```
NSString *levelstringfinal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level %d (%d/%d)", levelscore, xpscore, (levelscore*(levelscore+1)*100)];
```

The warning you're getting is because the compiler can't check a variable's content, whereas with a string literal it can match placeholders and variables for some degree of consistency.

(Even if you had to build the string in pieces, the last line would be better using `stringByAppendingString` rather than `stringByAppendingFormat` because those are no longer format specifiers.)